# XML strings to echo PHP

Tags: php, xml, attributes, simplexml

I have a sophisticated feed that I want to echo the values of the XML file to PHP table.

Below is a sample of the UK RailDataFeed (Aka Darwin).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-01-01T21:58:48.2213864Z" version="12.0">
    <uR updateOrigin="Trust">
        <TS>
            <Location pta="21:59" ptd="21:59" tpl="ROBY" wta="21:59" wtd="21:59:30">
                <arr at="21:59" src="TRUST" srcInst="Auto" />
                <dep et="21:59" src="Darwin" />
                <plat conf="true" platsrc="A">4</plat>
            </Location>
            <Location pta="22:06" ptd="22:06" tpl="PRESCOT" wta="22:05:30" wtd="22:06">
                <arr et="22:06" src="Darwin" wet="22:05" />
                <dep et="22:06" src="Darwin" />
                <plat>1</plat>
            </Location>
        </TS>
    </uR>
</Pport>
```

I have been trying and researching all day to try to get the echo working but without any luck, I have tried the following

Test (1)

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("log.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->Location[0]['tpl'] . "<br>";
echo $xml->Location[1]->arr['at']; 
echo $xml->Location[2]->dep['et']; 
echo $xml->Location[3]->plat;
```

Test (2)

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("log.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $loc) { 
    echo $loc->Location['tpl'];
    echo $loc->arr['at'];
    echo $loc->plat;
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```

Test (3)

```
    $file = file_get_contents('log.xml');
echo $file;
```

Still without any progress, After achieving this, I want to add the values to a bootstrap table too.

If any Ideas please share with me.

Comment: `$xml->Pport->uR->TS->Location[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can access attribute values via the [attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method. Also, note that values are cast to string when echoing.

```
$str = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-01-01T21:58:48.2213864Z" version="12.0">
    <uR updateOrigin="Trust">
        <TS>
            <Location pta="21:59" ptd="21:59" tpl="ROBY" wta="21:59" wtd="21:59:30">
                <arr at="21:59" src="TRUST" srcInst="Auto" />
                <dep et="21:59" src="Darwin" />
                <plat conf="true" platsrc="A">4</plat>
            </Location>
            <Location pta="22:06" ptd="22:06" tpl="PRESCOT" wta="22:05:30" wtd="22:06">
                <arr at="22:06" src="Darwin" wet="22:05" />
                <dep et="22:06" src="Darwin" />
                <plat>1</plat>
            </Location>
        </TS>
    </uR>
</Pport>
EOF;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$c = 0;
foreach($xml->uR->TS->Location as $loc) {
    echo (++$c) . "\n";
    echo (string)$loc->attributes()['tpl'] . "\n";
    echo (string)$loc->arr->attributes()['at'] . "\n";
    echo (string)$loc->dep->attributes()['et'] . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: I have additional question, on the XML source file which is 4MB big.
The file contains multiple headers inside, Is there a way to ignore the header so it won't be showing any errors.

Comment: You don't need `->attributes()` for normal attributes, only if you're working with different namespaces. Instead of `(string)$loc->attributes()['tpl']`, you can just write `(string)$loc['tpl']`.

Answer (score 0):

After @marekful reply.

code modified to

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('log.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$c = 0;
foreach($xml->uR->TS->Location as $loc) 
{
    echo (++$c) . "\n";
    echo (string)$loc->attributes()['tpl'] . "\n";
    echo (string)$loc->arr->attributes()['at'] . "\n";
    echo (string)$loc->dep->attributes()['et'] . "\n\n";
    echo (string)$loc->plat . "\n\n\n";
}
?>
```

And it worked perfectly with the sample xml file, but after adding the original XML file, It has multiple header in the file itself as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-01-03T01:31:28.3036616Z" version="12.0">
    <uR requestID="AM02050384" requestSource="AM02" updateOrigin="CIS">
        <TS rid="201801037171519" ssd="2018-01-03" uid="G71519">
            <ns3:Location tpl="GLYNDE" wtp="01:25:08">
                <ns3:pass at="01:31" src="TD" />
                <ns3:plat conf="true" platsrc="A" platsup="true">2</ns3:plat>
                <ns3:length>8</ns3:length>
            </ns3:Location>
        </TS>
    </uR>
</Pport>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-01-03T01:31:29.1772672Z" version="12.0">
    <uR requestID="0000000000046386" requestSource="at21" updateOrigin="CIS">
        <TS rid="201801038706030" ssd="2018-01-03" uid="W06030">
            <ns3:Location pta="01:25" ptd="01:26" tpl="DARTFD" wta="01:25" wtd="01:26">
                <ns3:arr at="01:31" src="TD" />
                <ns3:dep et="01:32" etmin="01:27" src="Darwin" />
                <ns3:plat conf="true" platsrc="A">4</ns3:plat>
            </ns3:Location>
        </TS>
    </uR>
</Pport>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-01-03T01:31:30.1912737Z" version="12.0">
    <uR updateOrigin="TD">
        <TS rid="201801027160109" ssd="2018-01-02" uid="G60109">
            <ns3:Location tpl="BRINKLW" wtp="01:34:30">
                <ns3:pass at="01:31" src="TD" /></ns3:Location>
        </TS>
    </uR>
</Pport>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-01-03T01:31:31.2052802Z" version="12.0">
    <uR updateOrigin="TD">
        <TS rid="201801036763188" ssd="2018-01-03" uid="C63188">
            <ns3:Location tpl="AMBERGJ" wtp="02:04:30">
                <ns3:pass et="01:38" src="TD" /></ns3:Location>
        </TS>
    </uR>
</Pport>
```

Is there a way to:

1. Ignore the multiple headers to avoid errors.
2. Post the echo value to a Bootstrap table.

Cheers!

Comment: No, multiple <xml> tags are invalid. You need to separately handle them and combine results in PHP code.

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to upvote and accept my answer if it helped you getting the XML attributes.

Comment: Please do not post additional questions in comments or answers; the format of this site is built around each page having one question at the top, and answers to that question below it. You might want to read through the [tour] and other pages in the [help] if you haven't already.